# Executing jQuery while transitioning from one Node route to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have some jQuery below:

```
$(function () {
    $('.mnav a').click(function () {
        el = $('.border');
        el.addClass('blink');
        el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            el.removeClass('blink');
        });
    });
});
```

It adds a class to an element for an animation then removes that class after the animation runs so every time I click a link that element animates.

That animation is running on elements that are in the <%- body %> tag of my layouts.ejs. When I go from the '/' route to the '/users/new' route I think the animation is happening on the '/' route but I dont see it because I'll be on the '/users/new' route.

The effect Im going for is that when a user clicks on the login link, the effect happens WHILE the going to the new route.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If going to the new route involves a page reload, no, this isn't possible.

Comment: right now im developing this locally and it goes from http://localhost:3000/ to http://localhost:3000/users/new. Im not sure if thats a page reload or not?

Comment: If it's not being done with ajax, it's being done with a page reload.

Comment: Is there a way to use ajax in this situation? I am completely new and have never used ajax before

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but would require a good bit of work on your end. you'd essentially be turning your website/application into a single page application, which has it's own set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the click event on all current elements and future ones :

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on("click",".mnav a",function () {
        el = $('.border');
        el.addClass('blink');
        el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            el.removeClass('blink');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That didnt work. I was hoping there was a way without using ajax, but it would seem not.